# Error when using pyautogui module in Mu-Editor

Tags: module, pyautogui, mu

I'm trying to write some code and import the pyautogui module, but am getting an error.

```
import pyautogui
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('https://roamresearch.com/#/app/test852')
b = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('JournalQuestions.png')
```

I'm getting the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/rika/mu_code/mouse.py", line 2, in 
import pyautogui
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add relevant code that shows what you've done so far.

Comment: Hi. You should add code to your question. I'm reviewing a lot of questions, not solving them all.

Comment: Sorry about that. Code added. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in the Mu-Editor community. I just needed to download the Alpha version from here: https://codewith.mu/en/download. Then click on Gears icon and there is a tab for importing packages. Very user friendly!